# Find occurrences where a comma is separated by numbers using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to find occurrences where a comma is separated by a number on either side.

For example:

```
SampleString ='A,B,C, 1, 2, 3, 4, G'
```

I need to replace the commas with all space before and after comma with just a comma(no space). I need to do this only if the comma is separating numbers.

```
CleanString =re.sub(r([0-9]+)\s?,\s?([0-9]+)' ,r"\g<1>,\g<2>",SampleString)
```

This output gives me `A,B,C, 1,2, 3,4, G`.
The output I need is `A,B,C, 1,2,3,4, G`

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'([0-9]+)\s*,\s*(?=[0-9])' , r'\1,',SampleString)`. See https://regex101.com/r/GI5t95/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
import re

SampleString = 'A, B,B, M1, 3, 44, 45, 46, 47, G, 1, 33'

CleanString = re.sub(r'(\b\d+)(\s*,\s*)(?=\d+\b)', r'\1,', SampleString)

print(CleanString)
```

Output:

```
A, B,B, M1, 3,44,45,46,47, G, 1,33
```

Comment: What if there are double digits? Such as 'A,B,C, 1, 3,4 , 44, G'?

Comment: @Ritika It works for those too, the one digit check is just a check, there could be more, but there can't be less.

Comment: Thank you!. Sorry but I have another question regarding this. What if I have a string which is 'A,B,C, M1, 3,4 , 44, G'.  I would need the output like: 'A,B,B, M1, 3,44, G'. in this case the M1 is giving me a problem

Comment: @Ritika In that case you can use the regex `(\b\d+)(\s*,\s*)(\d+\b)` (check the edit).

Comment: @MrGreek . It then goes back to my original problem. It only captures  in groups of two. So if there is an odd number of integers eg. 'A,B,B, M1, 3,44,5, G' , it does not capture the comma between 44 and 5. I could ask this as a new question if required

Comment: @Ritika In this case the regex shouldn't consume the right number (check the edit).

Answer (score 0):

```python
CleanString = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\s*,\s*(?=\d)", ",", SampleString)
```

`(?<=\d)` is a lookbehind that requires one digit (`\d`) to precede the current position

`(?=\d)` is a lookahead that requires one digit to follow the current position

You don't need to capture anything, i.e., you don't any extra parentheses. Anyway it may be good to know that lookaheads and lookbehinds are non-capturing (unless they contain parentheses inside).

Answer (score 0):

This regex uses lookahead:

`((\d+)\s*,\s*)(?=\d)`

This matches digits optionally followed by spaces followed by a comma optionally followed by spaces only if that sequence is followed by a digit. So, in the string `1, 2 , 3`, the first match is `1,`.

```
import re
SampleString ='A,B,C, 1, 2 , 3 , 4, G'
CleanString = re.sub(r'((\d+)\s*,\s*)(?=\d)', r"\g<2>,", SampleString)
print(CleanString)
```

Prints:

```
A,B,C, 1,2,3,4, G
```

Comment: Granted that I could have used lookbehind and just replaced with a `,` rather than a capture group for the number..